# Left join retornando somente determinados campos

Tags: sql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

## tb_agenda

<kbd>id_agenda</kbd><kbd>id_medico</kbd><kbd>data</kbd><kbd>hora</kbd>

## tb_paciente

<kbd>id_paciente</kbd><kbd>nome_paciente</kbd>

## tb_medico

<kbd>id_medico</kbd><kbd>nome_medico</kbd>

## tb_agendamento

<kbd>id_agendamento</kbd><kbd>id_agenda</kbd><kbd>id_paciente</kbd>

Faco a seguinte consulta

```
select * from tb_agenda as a left join tb_agendamento as b on (a.id_agenda=b.id_agenda)
```

Eu gostaria que me retornassem os seguintes campos: `id_agendamento, hora, nome_medico, nome_ paciente`

Comment: ele me retorna o nome da tb_agenda  , mas da tabela agendamento so me retorna os id eu queria os nomes .pois na tb_agendamento eu tenho chave fk  id_paciente eu queria que ela me retorna-se com campo nome_paciente .quando faco left join

Comment: nao sei  explicar bem , mas eu queria exibir os horarios do medico  na tabela agenda  e ao agenda paciente na tabela agendamento  ele fosse visualizado na  grade da tabela agenda  eu uso esse select * from tb_agenda as a left join tb_agendamento as b on (a.id_agenda=b.id_agenda)

Comment: obrigado funcionou!!!!obrigado mesmo vou por maos a obra agora :)

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT id_agendamento, hora, nome_medico, nome_paciente FROM tb_agenda AS agenda 
INNER JOIN tb_agendamento AS agendamento ON agenda.id_agenda = agendamento.id_agenda 
INNER JOIN tb_paciente AS paciente ON paciente.id_paciente = agendamento.id_paciente 
INNER JOIN tb_medico AS medico ON medico.id_medico = agenda.id_medico
```

Veja mais sobre como fazer relacionamento [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Existem ainda alguns adendos sobre a estrutura das suas tabelas.
Depende de qual regra de negocio pretende implementar, mas desse jeito na maioria dos casos ficaria melhor:

## tb_agenda

<kbd>id_agenda</kbd>:<kbd>int</kbd>

<kbd>data</kbd>:<kbd>timestamp</kbd>

<kbd>hora</kbd>:<kbd>time</kbd>

## tb_paciente

<kbd>id_paciente</kbd>:<kbd>int</kbd>

<kbd>nome_paciente</kbd>:<kbd>string</kbd>

## tb_medico

<kbd>id_medico</kbd>:<kbd>int</kbd>

<kbd>nome_medico</kbd>:<kbd>string</kbd>

## tb_agendamento

<kbd>id_agendamento</kbd>:<kbd>int</kbd>

<kbd>fk_agenda</kbd>:<kbd>int</kbd>

<kbd>fk_medico</kbd>:<kbd>int</kbd>

<kbd>fk_paciente</kbd>:<kbd>int</kbd>